# How use event placesAutocompleteOnChange at Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can not find information about event `placesAutocompleteOnChange`. I need show point at map after calling this event.
I tried:

```php
$this->config_map['placesAutocompleteOnChange']  = 'var place = placesAutocomplete.getPlace();
        var location = place.geometry.location;
        alert(JSON.stringify(location))';
```

So, How to reaload map with a market location?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for event `placesAutocompleteOnChange`:

```
var place = placesAutocomplete.getPlace();
             if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                 map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
             } else {
                 map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                 map.setZoom(17);
             }
```

Comment: It works, but when I zoom up/down map the marker is moved on map